# Obtaining potassium silicate from sodium silicate

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, home-experiment

Is it possible to obtain Potassium silicate ($\ce{K2SiO3}$) from Sodium silicate  ($\ce{Na2SiO3}$) without using expensive lab equipment such as furnaces etc.?

For example, Calcium silicate may be obtained using the following exchange reaction:

$$\ce{CaCl2 + Na2SiO3 ->  CaSiO3 v + 2NaCl}$$

Substituting calcium chloride with potassium chloride probably will not produce a similar result as potassium has different (less) electronegativity than sodium, though I am not sure if the exchange reaction takes place because of electronegativity (only).

(The aim is to be able to not only produce potassium silicate, but also separate it for example, as an aqueous solution without other solutes.)

Comment: Feel free to comment as I'm just learning and maybe asking a question that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sodium and potassium silicates have the same solubility in water. You cannot obtain one from the other.

Comment: This idea doesn't make much sense, but I guess one could do it, by first precipitating hydrated SiO2 and then reacting it with hydroxide.

Comment: I believe aqueous potassium silicate solutions are available commercially if that helps?

Comment: Thanks @Hendrix13, but that doesn't help. The question was not about buying potassium silicate.